# How I can disable and enable button based on user input in textinput component?

Tags: validation, react-native

I want to disable and enable button based on user input .If any field is empty then button must be disabled and if all field are fill up. Then button will be enabled in react-native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
  onChangeText(text){
    if (text.length == 0){
      // disable button
      this.setState({disabled: true})
    } else {
      // enable button
      this.setState({disabled: false})
    }
    this.setState({value: text})
  }
```

**render:**

```
       <TextInput 
          value={this.state.value}
          style={{backgroundColor: 'gray'}}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text)}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.disabled} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.disabled ? 'red': 'green'}} >
        <Text> Button </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

**Working Example**

https://snack.expo.io/S1y7Pr8BI

Answer (score 0):

use state tot handle this ... here is an example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
export default () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  console.log(email)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput placeholder="enter" onChangeText={setEmail} />
      <Button
        disabled={email ? false : true}
        title="Button"
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('sdasds')
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See below example hope this will help you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
  };

  onChangeName = value => {
    this.setState({
      name: value,
    });
  };

  checkUserDetails = () => {
    //
  };

  render() {
    const { name} = this.state;
    const { scrollview, inputStyle } = styles;

    return (
      <View style={styles.scrollview}>
        <View style={{ width: '90%', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
          <TextInput
            style={inputStyle}
            placeholder={` name`}
            placeholderTextColor={'#ED3C20'}
            onChangeText={this.onChangeName}
            value={name}
          />
          <Button
            disabled={!this.state.name ? true : false}
            title="submit"
            buttonHandler={this.checkUserDetails}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputStyle: {
    height: 45,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 5,
    textAlign: 'auto',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Feel free for doubts.